# Select rows which have no match in other table?

Tags: mysql, match

I have this structure 
tbl_site_urls: storing urls of a site

tbl_camp_urls: storing urls of a campaign, after handling these urls
tbl_site_urls

```
id - site_id - url
1  - 181     - url1
2  - 182     - url2
3  - 189     - url3
```

tbl_camp_urls

```
id - camp_id - site_id - url
1  - 5       - 181     - url1
```

if i want to list the urls need to be handle

```
select url from tbl_site_urls
  join site on tbl_site_urls.site_id = site.id AND site.valid=1
```

then in a loop operation I insert the handled urls into the tbl_camp_urls

I want to list the urls that which have not handled yet.
it is like a comparison operation.

**The results I'm expecting is**

```
2  - 182     - url2
3  - 189     - url3
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT a.urls
FROM tbl_site_urls as a
LEFT JOIN tbl_camp_urls as b
ON a.site_id = b.site_id
WHERE b.site_id IS NULL;
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, as it does not require returning _all_ the rows of the second table.

Comment: Perfect...you saved my butt. My head is so blocked right now that I couldn't think of the last part `WHERE b.site_id IS NULL`.  Thanks. +1.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
select  * from tbl_site_urls where url not in (select url from tbl_camp_urls)
```

(search for subqueries for more info on it)

Answer (score 0):

My logic tells me that you need to make a intersection to know the commons values and a union to remove them:

should be something like this:

**First get all the values:**

```
(select site_id from tbl_site_urls) 
union 
(select id from site)
```

**This is how you get the commons values ONLY**

```
(select url from tbl_site_urls inner join site on tbl_site_urls.site_id = site.id)
```

**Now lets put those queries together:**

```
select * from (select site_id from tbl_site_urls 
union 
select id from site) as tem_table
where
site_id not in
(select url from tbl_site_urls inner join site on tbl_site_urls.site_id = site.id) --commons values
```

Comment: that only will give you the values from 1 table that are not repeated in the 2 table, but not in both ways...try to put a different value in `tbl_camp_urls` table and it wont show up

Comment: As far as I can see that is what the OP wants... ?